# Create page navigation using php

Tags: php, foreach, navigation

I am having some issues trying to create page navigation using php,

I have variable called $PageNo that I can navigate through using using next prev links -1 or +1.

eg.

```
echo "<a href='http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/product.php?page=".($PageNo+1)."'>Next</a>";
echo "<a href='http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/product.php?page=".($PageNo-1)."'>Prev</a>";
```

but aswell as this is want to display direct links to the pages so i have a navigation like so

PREV 1 2 3 4 NEXT

```
echo "<a href='http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/product.php?page=".($PageNo+1)."'>Next</a>";
echo "<a href='http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/product.php?page=1'>1</a>";
echo "<a href='http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/product.php?page=2'>2</a>";
echo "<a href='http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/product.php?page=3'>3</a>";
echo "<a href='http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/product.php?page=4'>4</a>";
echo "<a href='http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/product.php?page=".($PageNo-1)."'>Prev</a>";
```

If I know the total number of product pages is 4 how would you generate the links to give

```
echo "<a href='http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/product.php?page=1'>1</a>";
echo "<a href='http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/product.php?page=2'>2</a>";
echo "<a href='http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/product.php?page=3'>3</a>";
echo "<a href='http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/product.php?page=4'>4</a>";
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: You have a syntax error. Remove the double quote (") after all links that contain static numbers (1-4). You're basically ending your string there, while you shouldn't.

Comment: Yes thanks, this was a typo, now corrected. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the math, and then a little bit of code.

1. calculate the number os pages you need (based on the number os records and records per page)
2. Just use a for loop to do links like (not tested):

   for ($page = 1; $page <= $total_pg; ++$page) {
   echo "$page";
   }

then, the product.php page reads that number and displays the subset of records

Answer (score 2):

How about to try this one?

```
// $total_num : total number of the pages
foreach (range(1, $total_num) as $p) {
    echo "<a href='http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/product.php?page=$p"'>$p</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple [for loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php), and it's very basic stuff that's in all programming languages out there (just like if/else statements and while loops among others).

Say the total number of pages is 4, then you set a random variable, say $p (for pages) initially to it's start value 1, then continue the loop, increasing $p by 1 every time until $p is 4. Would result in this:

```
// Previous link before the numbers (unless we are on page 1)
if($PageNo > 1) {
    echo "<a href='http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/product.php?page=".($PageNo-1)."'>Prev</a>";
}

// We loop over all the numbered pages here
for($p = 1;$p <= 4;$p++) {
    echo "<a href='http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/product.php?page=" . $p . "'>" . $p . "</a>";
}

// Next link goes after the numbers (if there are any pages left)
if(($PageNo + 1) <= $p) {
    echo "<a href='http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/product.php?page=".($PageNo+1)."'>Next</a>";
}
```